# Merging cropped images using non max suppression

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is the best way to crops a large image into smaller images to perform object detection on so that the results can be merged using non max suppression to remove possible duplicate bounding boxes?

Currently I am first cropping the large image of 6000*4000 into smaller images of 500*500 with this function wrapped in a for loop:

```
    crop_img = masterImage[y:y+imgSize, x:x+imgSize]
```

I then run object detection on each image. The results are then stored in a dictionary:

```
    boxesColect[Point(xCount,yCount)] = [boxes, scores, classes]
```

I then use this dictionary to create a tensor that I use for non max suppression.

Is there a better approach to this problem ?